# Failing to synchronise go routines

Tags: go, concurrency, mutex, goroutine

I was trying to implement a rate limter in golang. The algorithm i used is sliding window.

**Approach**

i am using a map to store number of request in a particular second. So when a new request comes it will calculate number of request in the prevois duration and if it exceeds the limit it won't allow the request to be served.

My main interface is

```
type RateLimiterSync interface {

    AllowRequest(userID string) (bool, error)
    Kill() error
}
```

Here **AllowRequest** is the main method which i will be called to validate if request will be allowed or not according to the parameter set for number of request allowed in a given timeframe.

The second Method **Kill()** is to kill a goroutine which will keep on removing the entries from the map which are not relevant in the given timeframe.

Also, i am storing the configuration of the rate limiter key wise in another map

```
type Config struct {
    //Duration of timeline
    Duration int
    //no of request allowed
    Count int
}
```

Here **Duration** is the time frame for evaluating the number of requests and **Count** is the number of requests allowed in that time frame
so for example, if Duration is 10 and the count is 10 then it will allow 10 requests to be served in 10 seconds

Then there is a type **SlidingWindowSync** which provides implementation for **RateLimiterSync**

Adding code for the implementation

```
type SlidingWindowSync struct {
    mutex            sync.Mutex
    keyReqMap        map[string]map[int]int
    keyConfigService *KeyConfigService
    stop             bool
}

func NewSlidingWindowSync(keyConfigService *KeyConfigService, userID string) *SlidingWindowSync {
    var rateLimiter *SlidingWindowSync
    rateLimiter = &SlidingWindowSync{
        keyConfigService: keyConfigService,
        mutex:            sync.Mutex{},
        keyReqMap:        make(map[string]map[int]int),
        stop:             false,
    }
    userConfig, _ := rateLimiter.keyConfigService.GetConfig(userID)
    go rateLimiter.removeEnteries(userID, userConfig.Duration, rateLimiter.mutex)
    return rateLimiter
}

//incrementCountSync : increment req count we can add mutex here
func incrementCountSync(reqMap map[int]int, curTimeInSec int, mutex sync.Mutex) {
    mutex.Lock()
    defer mutex.Unlock()
    if _, exists := reqMap[curTimeInSec]; exists == false {
        reqMap[curTimeInSec] = 1
    } else {
        reqMap[curTimeInSec] = reqMap[curTimeInSec] + 1
    }
}

func (r *SlidingWindowSync) Kill() error {
    var err error
    if r.stop == false {
        r.stop = true
        fmt.Println(" killing go routine")
    } else {
        err = fmt.Errorf(" go routine already stopped")
    }
    return err
}

func (r *SlidingWindowSync) removeEnteries(configKey string, durationInSec int, mutex sync.Mutex) {
    for {
        if r.stop {
            fmt.Println(" existing the go routine ------")
            break
        }
        fmt.Println(" taking a lock in go routine")
        mutex.Lock()
        for key, _ := range r.keyReqMap[configKey] {
            if time.Now().UTC().Second()-key > durationInSec {
                fmt.Println(" deleting key for second =", time.Now().UTC().Second()-key)
                delete(r.keyReqMap[configKey], key)
            }
        }
        mutex.Unlock()
        fmt.Println(" existing a lock in go routine")
        time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(durationInSec) / 10)
    }

}
func getReqCountSync(reqMap map[int]int, curTimeInSec int,
    durationInSec int, mutex sync.Mutex) int {
    var count int
    if len(reqMap) == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    mutex.Lock()
    defer mutex.Unlock()
    //Applying a lock over the critical section of the map
    for key, value := range reqMap {
        if curTimeInSec-key < durationInSec {
            count += value
        }
    }
    return count
}

//AllowRequest : this is the main impl for the rate limiter
func (s *SlidingWindowSync) AllowRequest(userID string) (bool, error) {
    var (
        reqMap     map[int]int
        userConfig *domains.Config
        err        error
        curTime    = time.Now().UTC().Second()
    )
    //Get the config service
    if userConfig, err = s.keyConfigService.GetConfig(userID); err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    //Check in map for req count
    if _, exists := s.keyReqMap[userID]; !exists {
        s.keyReqMap[userID] = make(map[int]int)
    }
    reqMap = s.keyReqMap[userID]
    if getReqCountSync(reqMap, curTime, userConfig.Duration, s.mutex) >= userConfig.Count {
        return false, nil
    }
    incrementCountSync(reqMap, curTime, s.mutex)
    return true, nil
}
```

So mainly the **AllowRequest** is extracting the config for the key and then checking if number of request in the time frame are valid or not ?
Also i am running a seperate goroutine each time when **NewSlidingWindowSync** is intialized which will keep on removing enteries from the map which are not relevant for the time frame.
Adding the main implementaion

```
func main() {
    keyConfigService := services.NewKeyConfigService()
    keyConfigService.Upsert("login", domains.NewConfig(10, 10))
    rateLimiter := services.NewSlidingWindowSync(keyConfigService, "login")
    startTime := time.Now().UTC().Second()
    for index := 0; index < 40; index++ {
        if allow, err := rateLimiter.AllowRequest("login"); err != nil {
            fmt.Errorf(" error = %+v", err)
        } else if allow {
            fmt.Printf(" request allowed at %d second \n",
                time.Now().UTC().Second()-startTime)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf(" request aborted at %d second \n",
                time.Now().UTC().Second()-startTime)
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)
    }

}
```

Here i am testing the implementation by calling the go routine with a delay of 0.5 second each time.

Though in main i am getting some time a negative value in printing statements i feel this is because of synchronisation issue.
Adding output of main for the above code

```
request allowed at 0 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 existing a lock in go routine
 request allowed at 0 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 existing a lock in go routine
 request allowed at 1 second 
 request allowed at 1 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 existing a lock in go routine
 request allowed at 2 second 
 request allowed at 2 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 existing a lock in go routine
 request allowed at 3 second 
 request allowed at 3 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 existing a lock in go routine
 request allowed at 4 second 
 request allowed at 4 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 existing a lock in go routine
 request aborted at 5 second 
 request aborted at 5 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 existing a lock in go routine
 request aborted at 6 second 
 request aborted at 6 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 existing a lock in go routine
 request aborted at 7 second 
 request aborted at 7 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 existing a lock in go routine
 request aborted at 8 second 
 request aborted at 8 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 existing a lock in go routine
 request aborted at 9 second 
 request aborted at 9 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 existing a lock in go routine
 request allowed at 10 second 
 request allowed at 10 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 deleting key for second = 11
 existing a lock in go routine
 request allowed at 11 second 
 request allowed at 11 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 deleting key for second = 11
 existing a lock in go routine
 request allowed at 12 second 
 request allowed at 12 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 deleting key for second = 11
 existing a lock in go routine
 request allowed at 13 second 
 request allowed at 13 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 deleting key for second = 11
 existing a lock in go routine
 request allowed at 14 second 
 request allowed at 14 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 deleting key for second = 11
 existing a lock in go routine
 request aborted at 15 second 
 request aborted at 15 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 existing a lock in go routine
 request aborted at -44 second 
 request aborted at -44 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 existing a lock in go routine
 request aborted at -43 second 
 request aborted at -43 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 existing a lock in go routine
 request aborted at -42 second 
 request aborted at -42 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 existing a lock in go routine
 request aborted at -41 second 
 request aborted at -41 second 
 taking a lock in go routine
 existing a lock in go routine
```

Need help with why i am getting negative values some times as **startTime** would always be less ? Thanks for the help

Comment: "Second returns the second offset within the minute specified by t, in the range [0, 59]." Did you mean to use time.Unix()? Don't do that though. Use time.Since() and remove the UTC calls to account for clock adjustments. See https://pkg.go.dev/time#hdr-Monotonic_Clocks

Comment: understood, so shall i also store seconds in the format of seconds in my map key for comptation purposes ?

Comment: You should store time.Time and time.Duration values only and do call computations using time.Since, time.Sub, time.Add etc.